# Add a delimiter to a list in python at specific locations

Tags: python, list, replace, location, delimiter

I have a list that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to:

(1) Scan the first element in the list

(2) Identify the locations of all the "|"

(3) In the rest of the elements of the list inspect the given locations listed in (2)

(4) If at said location there is a space, " ", then replace it with a "|"

So that the output looks like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include your current Python code.  These screen captures look more like SQL or Excel tables than Python lists.

Comment: Each row is an element within the list. I cannot provide my data but I can provide the code I used to generate the list:

Comment: 'code' test = open("data.txt","r")
lines = test.readlines()

lines2 = [re.sub(r" (?=\S)", "|", i) for i in lines]

Answer (score 0):

First, separate out the first line and get the indices of the `"|"` character:

`indices = [i for (i, c) in enumerate(line) if c == "|"]`

Then iterate through your remaining lines and apply the following. Note that strings are immutable, so to change a character you'll have to put them in something else first. There are many approaches, but I'll put all the characters in a list, replace the character, then re-join the characters in the list into one string.

```
for i in indices:
    line = list(line)
    if line[i] == " ":
        line[i] = "|"
line = "".join(line)
```